# Model UVs optimization

Tags: texture, optimisation, uv-mapping

This is related to [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268554/texture-coordinates-for-part-of-model) *(but the purpose of this question is different)*.

I have model with *UVs* (3DS max UVW editor screenshot)

[image: 3dsmax uvws editor screenshot]

I have grouped some unused parts of *UVs* on the top right corner. *Bump map* is 512x512 (large enough), so Id like to decrease its dimensions if possible (e.g. tile a texture of smaller size). Currently I am using only *bump map* for the top part of the object and this solution is enough for now, but I want to improve it.

I am asking for advice:

- How to optimize this *UVs* mapping to be more universal and applicable for future usage (best practice/article/advice/example/other, leading to right direction)?
- What steps and techniques I will need to do to use multiple *UVs* for single object (I would like make each texture obtain all avalable space)?

P.S. For the second question:

Imagine a cube with image of "sun" on left side, bump map on right side and another combinations of textures on rest sides. Then (in case of single UV) UVs would be divided into 9 parts (6 for each side and 3 unused free space) and each texture (for example image of "sun") can obtain only a part of texture space and the rest space - empty. Greater dimensions of each texture is needed to get better result.

So, I am looking for a way to do like so (make each texture use max avalable space):

[image]

Comment: This is probably a a dumb question, but do you mean uv, instead of uwv? Are there 3 components to your texture coordinate? And if so, why is it uwv, not uvw?

Comment: @AlanWolfe The titlebar in the screenshot says "Edit UVWs" so the questioner probably means that.

Comment: @AlanWolfe I have a lack of experience in 3D graphics, so I called it according to 3DSMax modifier name "Unwrap UVW". Renamed to UVs to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Instead of using multiple UV's for different texture types (albedo, normal, etc.), you should use single UV and multiple textures for different types.

Comment: @JarkkoL, texture of greater size is needed in case of single UVs. For example, my model should have bump on the top part and image on the rest part - then single UVs would be divided into two parts: for bump and for image. Each texture map will use only a half of avalable space (image with "sun" illustrates a cube UVs with 6 different texture maps for each side).

Comment: In general models have all types of textures used for all the parts with matching UV space thus single UV channel is fine. E.g. you would allocate both normal & albedo textures for the top part of your model. Furthermore you should try to have constant pixel density for a good UV map. You are talking about very specific UV space optimization but this isn't the way models are UV mapped in general, IME.

Comment: You may want to split this up into two separate questions because they are different use cases (might help with getting answers). For your first question though, you say you want to tile a texture (presumably to save space). What do you mean by this? Are talking about overlapping the four triangles, or something totally different?